# Consistency. If I write 'recognize' with a 'z' do I have to write 'characterize' with a 'z' too?

Tags: american-english, british-english, orthography

I'm translating a book and need to keep the English orthography consistent. I'm a native 'British English' speaker. I know in British English you can often use either 'ize' or 'ise' endings. My problem is that instinctively 'recognize' feels right, but 'characterize' looks wrong. But for the sake of consistency do I have to write 'characterize' (or alternatively change all the endings to 'ise' and write 'recognise')

Comment: It looked odd to me as well, but it seems that [*characteri**z**e*](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/characterize) is indeed how it's spelt in AmE. Some dictionaries will highlight spellings particular to American English. There *are* words that end with -ise in AmE (e.g. reprise), but where you have a choice, it's usually good to be consistent with your choice of 'dialect'.

Comment: Thanks a lot for the prompt answer. My problem is more that I'm wondering if I can get away with writing 'recognize' since that's the way I learned it as a British English speaker, but at the same time use 'characterise' on the grounds that the specific word 'recognize' is also British English while 'characterize' is not.

Comment: Sure - the consistency is with the language variant, not with particular letter combinations.

Comment: I've considered writing a book or story in which British characters' dialog is spelled in BrE fashion, and American characters' dialog is spelled in AmE fashion.  For example, in a chapter where a British art critic and his American counterpart are talking, I would have the Brit say, "Rembrandt's use of colour here is remarkable", and I would have the Yank reply, "Yes, I've always admired his sense of color."

Comment: That might add colo/u/r to the read but the audio version wouldn't work too well :-).

Comment: tautophile, I think that might get kind of annoying after about 3 pages.